# Find all functions such that $f(m)+f(n)|m^p+n^p$

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, functional-equations, integers

For fixed prime number $p$, find all $f:\mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(m)+f(n)\mid m^p+n^p$ for all $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$

I managed to get only that for prime $q$ we have $f(q)=q^k$ for some nonnegative integer $k$.

Comment: The above link deals with a more general setting. In the case of this question, the result would be rephrased as follows: If $ p = 2 $, then $ f ( n ) = n ^ 2 $ for all $ n \in \mathbb Z _ + $; otherwise, either $ f ( n ) = n $ for all $ n \in \mathbb Z _ + $, or $ f ( n ) = n ^ p $ for all $ n \in \mathbb Z _ + $.